# Code is crashing in emulator and don't know why. New to android/java development

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm very new to both android and java development.  I am attempting to build an easy app.  It is currently very easy but I cannot seem to get the code to run.  As soon as I run the app in the emulator it spits out an alert saying my app has stopped.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.ultimatescoreclock;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // variables for the clock
    byte minRemaining = 0;
    byte secRemaining = 0;
    long msRemaining = 360000;  // six minutes
    TextView mainClock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clockMain);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public byte getMinutes(long millisUntilFinished) {
        return (byte) (millisUntilFinished / 60000);
    }

    public void onMainClockClick() {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("");

        str.append(minRemaining + ":" + secRemaining);
        mainClock.setText(str);
    }
}
```

Could someone please let me know what silly mistake I have made here?  FYI - My XML document has the onClick property set for the `R.id.mainClock` TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mainClock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clockMain);
```

has to be placed **after** `setContentView();`

This is because you first have to set the layout that your `Activity` uses and only then can you work with it. What is happening is your Object is being created, and your global variable (mainClock) is accessing something that does not exist yet because `onCreate()` has not gotten called yet.

So change `TextView mainClock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clockMain);` to

```
TextView mainClock;
```

and onCreate() should look like.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainClock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clockMain); //finds the clock TextView
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**-** You **can define** but **Not initialize** a `View` **before** the `setContentView()` method.

**-** `TextView mainClock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clockMain);` **before** `setContentView()` **is causing the crash.**

**-** Its **only after** the `setContentView()` method, one can **assign ids** to the `Views`, cause **till then** the `Views` **aren't initialized**.

**-** That's the whole point of using `setContentView(...)`, it **inflates** the `XML layout` file and **until you have an inflated View of some sort you won't be able to get a reference to any part of it**

**Eg:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainClock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clockMain); 
    }
```